# Rough LZ4 decompression of raw data with LZ4 Java

Tags: java, compression, lz4

I'm taking on a project to decompress data that is compressed with LZ4, but is also no longer in proper files in the file system. I mean for example I have a full disk image, and a large portion of that has LZ4-compressed data. I just found the open source Java implementation of LZ4 compressor/decompressor (by jpountz/Adrien Grand), [LZ4 Java](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java). I would like to use that, or modify if possible, to build a Java tool for these purposes.

Right now I see in an example-
https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java/blob/master/src/test/net/jpountz/example/LZ4Example.java

It looks rather simple to compress and decompress. For decompressing, a person must know either uncompressed or compressed data length.

I think I won't know the length of files contained in the compressed data. And I also won't know the beginning and end of files within the image file. But as an experiment, I have cropped smaller chunks of data out of that image and used [7-Zip ZS](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd) (supports LZ4) to extract proper files (like an XML file that is complete and correct). But that only retrieved one or two files at a time.

I have data processing experience, but haven't worked with LZ4 compression before (or really any compression in a programming project). Does anyone have idea for how I should go about this? For someone knowledgeable on LZ4 Java, does this seem feasible?

Also, I wonder how did 7-Zip extract/decompress perfect files? It must know where the file started and ended. Here I have some reading on the ["LZ4 Block Format Description"](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Block_format.md). But any additional insight is appreciated.

Keep in mind this project is not meant to extract everything perfectly. Some is better than none. Thanks for any input.